# Javascript: Why does vscode's autocompletion not find object-specific suggestions in some cases?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm trying to understand why vsCode's autocomplete function will sometimes give me a list of all members of a certain object and sometimes only a short list of options that I have used before but have nothing to do with the object in question, as seen in the images below.

For me as a beginner it's so very important to be able to explore the Document Object Model with the help of visual suggestions and from my limited understanding I just can't spot any difference between the two examples I'm looking at. The code below is all that there is in the current file (for simplicity):

```
const myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

From `myCanvas.` I would get all suggestions as expected, like "getContext", whereas from `myContext.` I only get an assortment of some items I've used before, but none of the methods or fields of the renderingContext2d-object, like "beginPath".
Why is that and is there anything I can do to get all suggestions?

[vsCode with incomplete autocomplete suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnwwI.png)

[VsCode with complete autocomplete suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM2ol.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
const myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

The type of the return value of this function is based on the parameter so vscode doesn't actually know what type "myContext" is. So it can't auto suggest anything.

While with

```
const myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
```

The function always returns a DOM element type so vscode can auto suggest DOM element methods and properties.

Comment: The first part kind of makes sense to me, thank you already. However, as far as I can understand it, `getElementById()` returns a DOM element object and `getContext()` isn't a method of that class, so why is it being suggested nonetheless?

Comment: Did you write "getContext()" somewhere else in the file? I can't repro getting that autocomplete suggestion without using it previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSDoc style type annotations](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html), but you should know which type of element you'll get from document.getElementById.
In your example this type is HTMLCanvasElement, what you can define like that:

```
/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
const myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
/** @type {CanvasRenderingContext2D} */
const myContext = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

After that, myCanvas.get... will give you "getContext" hint.

Comment: That's probably a very good answer to 'what can I do about it' but just too high level for me unfortunately. Thank you though